# Find a Bézier for 3 points and derivatives

Tags: geometry, bezier-curve

How to find a cubic Bézier curve in 2D space if the following is known:

- the start point of the curve (`P0`)
- the end point of the curve (`P3`)
- a point in the middle the curve goes through (`A`), i.e. `B(t) = A` for some `t`
- the first derivative in the start point (a direction from `P0` to `P1`, call it `u`), the length of the vector is either `0` or `1`
- the first derivative in the end point (a direction from `P3` to `P2`, call it  `v`), the length of the vector is either `0` or `1`
- `t` is provided in which `B(t) = A` should be met

The goal is to compute `P1` and `P2`.

Regarding the above, `P1 = P0 + k * u` and `P2 = P3 + l * v` for some `k` and `l`.

If the equations for `P1` and `P2` are put into the Bézier curve formula, only `k` and `l` are unknown. As the computation is made in 2D space, the formula splits to two, once for each dimension (`x` and `y`). As such, the problem is solvable.

However, when finding formulas for `k` and `l` there are two divisions made with denominators `3 * (1 - t)^2 * t * u.x` and `3 * (1 - t) * t^2 * (v.y * u.x - v.x * u.y)`.

I am lost what to do when one of these denominators is `0` which should occur when:

- `t = 0`, i.e. `A = P0`
- `t = 1`, i.e. `A = P3`
- `u.x = 0`, i.e. `P0.x = P1.x`
- Cross product of `u` and `v` is `0`, i.e. the derivatives in the start and end points have the same direction or they have the exact opposite direction (`u || v`) or one or both of them are a zero vector (`u = 0` or `v = 0`)

Does the cubic Bézier curve exists in these cases? If so, how to find it?

Or is there a better approach?